A self-defined function causes an error in defining a class object in a previous Python file
I am trying to run a self-defined function by importing classes and methods from another file. No matter what changes I make in the previous file, I keep on getting the same error message from pycharm.
Code snippet from the first file:
import random
class Coin:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def flip(self):
        return random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])

class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, 6)

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = 0
    def update_position(self, delta):
        self.position += delta
    def make_turn(self, coin, dice):
        coin_toss = coin.flip()
        dice_roll = dice.roll()
        if coin_toss == 'heads':
            movement = 1
        else:
            movement = -1
        self.update_position(movement * dice_roll)

class Game:
    def __init__(self, player, coin, dice):
        self.player = player
        self.coin = coin
        self.dice = dice
        pass
    def play(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.player.make_turn(self.coin, self.dice)
            return self.player.position

Snippet from the second file :
from randomwalk import Game


def startSimulation():
    num_games = 100
    position = 0
    for i in range(num_games):
        games = Game('Alex', 'heads', 3)
        end_position = games.play()
        position += end_position

    average_position = position/num_games
    print('Average position after'+ str(num_games)+ 'games(20 moves per game) is' + str(average_position))

startSimulation()

The error message :
D:\Python\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\Python\pythonProject\simulation.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\pythonProject\simulation.py", line 15, in <module>
    startSimulation()
  File "D:\Python\pythonProject\simulation.py", line 9, in startSimulation
    end_position = games.play()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\pythonProject\randomwalk.py", line 36, in play
    self.player.make_turn(self.coin, self.dice)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'make_turn'

Process finished with exit code 1


Look at how you are creating your game objects: Game('Alex', 'heads', 3). What other types of objects are you using here?

The class Game() is not expecting 2 strings and an integer as part of instantiating an instance. It is expecting 3 different class instances. Either that or Game() needs to immediately use the given parameters to create instance of the appropriate classes.

There is no place in your game for a player name. It would make sense to put that on the Player class. Do you intend to have a name per Player?

When creating a Game object with games = Game('Alex', 'heads', 3), the parameters should be instances of Player, Coin, and Dice, not strings.
Also, the play method in the Game class runs a loop for 20 turns, but the return statement immediately exits after the first turn. The return should be moved outside the loop to return the final position after 20 turns.

Hi, understood and obliged with what you recommended in the second paragraph. Could you please explain the class insatances with an example.

You need to pass it like this: games = Game(Player(), Coin() , Dice())

This makes it so that you can use these instances in the games inside the game object.

Thank you so much for helping me out. Grateful to you.
